# Problems inserting items in a database using SQLite in C#

Tags: c#, sqlite, insert

i am trying to insert items in a database using SQLite but when i call loadfunction i receive an error like out of index. I think the problem is when i call add function. I checked parameters values and all seems to be ok, but the elements are not inserted in the table. Bellow you will see my table, add function and load function.

The table:

```
CREATE TABLE `Fisiere` (
    `Nume`  TEXT,
    `Dimensiune`    INTEGER,
    `Data`  BLOB,
    `Rating_imdb`   REAL,
    `Cale`  TEXT
);
```

The insert function:

```
public void addFisier(DirectorVideo[] directors)
        {
            var dbCommand = new SQLiteCommand();
            dbCommand.Connection = _dbConnection;
            dbCommand.CommandText = "insert into Fisiere(Nume, Dimensiune, Data, Rating_imdb, Cale) values(@nume, @dimensiune, @data, @rating_imdb, @cale);";
            try {
                _dbConnection.Open();
                dbCommand.Transaction = _dbConnection.BeginTransaction();
                for (int i = 0; i < directors.Length - 1; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < directors[i].nrFisiere; j++)
                    {
                        var numeParam = new SQLiteParameter("@nume");
                        numeParam.Value = directors[i].fisiere[j].numeFisier;
                        var dimensiuneParam = new SQLiteParameter("@dimensiune");
                        dimensiuneParam.Value = directors[i].fisiere[j].dimensiune;
                        var dataParam = new SQLiteParameter("@data");
                        dataParam.Value = directors[i].fisiere[j].data;
                        var ratingParam = new SQLiteParameter("rating_imdb");
                        IMDb rat = new IMDb(directors[i].fisiere[j].numeFisier);
                        ratingParam.Value = rat.Rating;
                        var caleParam = new SQLiteParameter("cale");
                        caleParam.Value = directors[i].cale;

                        Console.WriteLine(numeParam.Value);

                        dbCommand.Parameters.Add(numeParam);
                        dbCommand.Parameters.Add(dimensiuneParam);
                        dbCommand.Parameters.Add(dataParam);
                        dbCommand.Parameters.Add(ratingParam);
                        dbCommand.Parameters.Add(caleParam);



                        Console.WriteLine(caleParam.Value);


                        dbCommand.Transaction.Commit();
                        Console.WriteLine("A fost inserat");

                    }
                }


            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("muie");
                dbCommand.Transaction.Rollback();
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (_dbConnection.State != ConnectionState.Closed) _dbConnection.Close();

            }
        }
```

Load file function

```
public void LoadFiles()
        {
            const string stringSql = "PRAGMA database_list";
            try
            {
                _dbConnection.Open();
                SQLiteCommand sqlCommand = new SQLiteCommand(stringSql, _dbConnection);
                SQLiteDataReader sqlReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
                try
                {
                    while (sqlReader.Read())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("se afiseaza");

                        Console.WriteLine((long)sqlReader["Id_fisier"]);
                        Console.WriteLine((string)sqlReader["Nume"]);
                        Console.WriteLine((long)sqlReader["Dimensiune"]);
                        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Parse((string)sqlReader["Data"]));
                        Console.WriteLine((long)sqlReader["Rating_imdb"]);
                        Console.WriteLine((string)sqlReader["Cale"]);

                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    // Always call Close when done reading.
                    sqlReader.Close();
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (_dbConnection.State != ConnectionState.Closed) _dbConnection.Close();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need to `Commit` your transaction. You call `BeginTransaction()` but you never commit your transaction so the data never gets written to the DB. Check this out for the details and workflow with Transactions. https://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html

The other problem is that your Transactions and your Commands are all out of order. You need to execute your commands within your transaction and then commit the transaction.

```
    public void addFisier(DirectorVideo[] directors)
        {
            SQLiteTransaction dbTrans;

            try
            {
                _dbConnection.Open();

                // Start Transaction first.
                dbTrans = _dbConnection.BeginTransaction();

                for (int i = 0; i < directors.Length - 1; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < directors[i].nrFisiere; j++)
                    {
                        // Create commands that run based on your number of inserts.
                        var dbCommand = new SQLiteCommand();
                        dbCommand.Connection = _dbConnection;
                        dbCommand.CommandText = "insert into Fisiere(Nume, Dimensiune, Data, Rating_imdb, Cale) values(@nume, @dimensiune, @data, @rating_imdb, @cale);";
                        dbCommand.Transaction = dbTrans;

                        var numeParam = new SQLiteParameter("@nume");
                        numeParam.Value = directors[i].fisiere[j].numeFisier;
                        var dimensiuneParam = new SQLiteParameter("@dimensiune");
                        dimensiuneParam.Value = directors[i].fisiere[j].dimensiune;
                        var dataParam = new SQLiteParameter("@data");
                        dataParam.Value = directors[i].fisiere[j].data;
                        var ratingParam = new SQLiteParameter("rating_imdb");
                        IMDb rat = new IMDb(directors[i].fisiere[j].numeFisier);
                        ratingParam.Value = rat;
                        var caleParam = new SQLiteParameter("cale");
                        caleParam.Value = directors[i].cale;

                        Console.WriteLine(numeParam.Value);

                        dbCommand.Parameters.Add(numeParam);
                        dbCommand.Parameters.Add(dimensiuneParam);
                        dbCommand.Parameters.Add(dataParam);
                        dbCommand.Parameters.Add(ratingParam);
                        dbCommand.Parameters.Add(caleParam);

                        Console.WriteLine(caleParam.Value);

                        Console.WriteLine("A fost inserat");

                        // Actually execute the commands.
                        dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }

                // If everything is good, commit the transaction.
                dbTrans.Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("muie");
                dbTrans.Rollback();
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (_dbConnection.State != ConnectionState.Closed) _dbConnection.Close();

            }
        }
```

Here is also a snippet from the SQLiteTransaction Class documentation. I suggest reading it: https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/sqlite/docs/Devart.Data.SQLite~Devart.Data.SQLite.SQLiteTransaction.html

```
public static void RunSQLiteTransaction(string myConnString) { 
    using (SQLiteConnection sqConnection = new SQLiteConnection(myConnString)) { 
        sqConnection.Open(); 
        // Start a local transaction 
        SQLiteTransaction myTrans = sqConnection.BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted); 
        SQLiteCommand sqCommand = sqConnection.CreateCommand(); 
        try { 
            sqCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Dept(DeptNo, DName) Values(52, 'DEVELOPMENT')"; 
            sqCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
            sqCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Dept(DeptNo, DName) Values(62, 'PRODUCTION')"; 
            sqCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
            myTrans.Commit(); 
            Console.WriteLine("Both records are written to database."); 
        } 
        catch (Exception e) { 
            myTrans.Rollback(); 
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString()); 
            Console.WriteLine("Neither record was written to database."); 
        } 
        finally { 
            sqCommand.Dispose(); 
            myTrans.Dispose(); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Update your code with the changes so we can at least verify it is where it should be.

Comment: @AlexChihaia I updated my answer with some more information. You are never executing your commands and also your new `Commit` is in the wrong place.

Comment: Oppps. Had to edit, had `_dbConnection` calls flipped.